# How to read and write out to a config.ini file in Python?

Tags: python, file, config

I'am currently using a `config.ini` file to load my python program. But my problem is that I couldn't manage to read them out correctly.

My config file looks like this:

> style.appearance.value="white"
>   money.user.value="23000"

I am currently using this this script to read from it:

```py
    class menu():
        def appearance(self,value):
            with open("config.ini", "r+") as file:
                data = file.readlines()
                print(data[0])
```

It prints out the whole string what I want to archive, but I would want it more like this:

```py
    class menu():
        def appearance(self,value):
            with open("config.ini", "r+") as file:
                data = file.readlines()
                style.appearance.value = data[0]
                print(style.appearance.value)
```

And then should the result be `"white"`.

Comment: Try using a **json** file as a config file instead.  It's built like a dictionary and there is a built-in 'json' package to read / write it.

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html for reading your ini file. `configparser ` is your friend in this case.